TrueType Font Parsing issue in plain C
I'm having an issue when parsing TrueType Fonts.
Below is the function responsible for parsing a simple glyph, but it has a problem that I can't find. I have attached an image that visualises the contours of the glyph. The X and Y coordinates of the glyph points don't seem to be quite correct. I have checked with many online resources but cannot find a problem.
Yes, I'm aware that TTF's are big endian.
What am I doing wrong?

#define ON_CURVE_POINT_BIT 0
#define X_SHORT_VECTOR_BIT 1
#define Y_SHORT_VECTOR_BIT 2
#define REPEAT_FLAG_BIT 3
#define X_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR 4
#define Y_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR 5

typedef struct
{
    short X;
    short Y;
    bool OnCurve;
} GlyphPoint;
typedef struct
{
    bool IsCompound;
    short NumOfContours;
    short MinX;
    short MinY;
    short MaxX;
    short MaxY;
    short unsigned* ContourEndIndices;
    short unsigned NumOfPoints;
    GlyphPoint* Points;
    char unsigned* Flags;
    short unsigned NumOfInstructions;
    char unsigned* Instructions;
} Glyph;

void Font_Parse(int unsigned FontIndex, char const* FilePath)
{
    FILE* File = 0;
    fopen_s(&File, FilePath, "rb");

    memset(&sFonts[FontIndex], 0, sizeof(Font));

    sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.ScalerType = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.NumTables = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.SearchRange = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.EntrySelector = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.RangeShift = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);

    for (short unsigned TableIndex = 0; TableIndex < sFonts[FontIndex].OffsetTable.NumTables; TableIndex++)
    {
        FontTableDirectory TableDir = {};
        FileReader_ReadInt8Array(File, TableDir.Tag, 4);
        TableDir.CheckSum = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
        TableDir.Offset = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
        TableDir.Length = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);

        if (strncmp(TableDir.Tag, "head", 4) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(&sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTableDir, &TableDir, sizeof(FontTableDirectory));
        }
        else if (strncmp(TableDir.Tag, "glyf", 4) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(&sFonts[FontIndex].GlyfTableDir, &TableDir, sizeof(FontTableDirectory));
        }
        else if (strncmp(TableDir.Tag, "loca", 4) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(&sFonts[FontIndex].LocaTableDir, &TableDir, sizeof(FontTableDirectory));
        }
        else if (strncmp(TableDir.Tag, "cmap", 4) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(&sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTableDir, &TableDir, sizeof(FontTableDirectory));
        }
        else if (strncmp(TableDir.Tag, "maxp", 4) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(&sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTableDir, &TableDir, sizeof(FontTableDirectory));
        }
    }

    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTableDir.Offset);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].GlyfTableDir.Offset);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].LocaTableDir.Offset);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTableDir.Offset);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTableDir.Offset);

    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTableDir.Offset, SEEK_SET);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.Version = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.FontRevision = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.CheckSumAdjustment = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MagicNumber = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.Flags = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.UnitsPerEm = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.Created = FileReader_ReadInt64(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.Modified = FileReader_ReadInt64(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MinX = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MinY = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MaxX = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MaxY = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MacStyle = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.LowestRecPPEM = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.FontDirectionHint = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.IndexToLocFormat = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.GlyphDataFormat = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.Version == 0x10000);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.MagicNumber == 0x5F0F3CF5);

    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTableDir.Offset, SEEK_SET);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.Version = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.NumGlyphs = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxPoints = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxContours = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxComponentPoints = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxComponentContours = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxZones = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxTwilightPoints = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxStorage = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxFunctionDefs = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxInstructionDefs = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxStackElements = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxSizeOfInstructions = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxComponentElements = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.MaxComponentDepth = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.Version == 0x10000);

    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTableDir.Offset, SEEK_SET);
    sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTable.Version = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTable.NumberSubTables = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    assert(sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTable.Version == 0x0);

    sFonts[FontIndex].Glyphs = (Glyph*)Memory_Alloc(sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.NumGlyphs * sizeof(Glyph), 0);
    sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphOffsets = (int unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.NumGlyphs * sizeof(int unsigned), 0);

    for (short unsigned GlyphIndex = 0; GlyphIndex < sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.NumGlyphs; GlyphIndex++)
    {
        if (sFonts[FontIndex].HeadTable.IndexToLocFormat)
        {
            fseek(File, (long)(sFonts[FontIndex].LocaTableDir.Offset + (GlyphIndex * 4U)), SEEK_SET);
            sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphOffsets[GlyphIndex] = sFonts[FontIndex].GlyfTableDir.Offset + FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(File, (long)(sFonts[FontIndex].LocaTableDir.Offset + (GlyphIndex * 2U)), SEEK_SET);
            sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphOffsets[GlyphIndex] = sFonts[FontIndex].GlyfTableDir.Offset + FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true) * 2U;
        }
    }

    sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphMapping = Font_UnicodeToGlyphMappingsInternal(File, FontIndex);

    //long long unsigned GlyphMapCount = Vector_Count(sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphMapping);

    for (short unsigned GlyphIndex = 0; GlyphIndex < sFonts[FontIndex].MaxpTable.NumGlyphs; GlyphIndex++)
    {
        memset(&sFonts[FontIndex].Glyphs[GlyphIndex], 0, sizeof(Glyph));

        //GlyphMap* GlyphMapping = (GlyphMap*)Vector_At(sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphMapping, GlyphMapIndex);

        Font_ReadGlyphInternal(File, FontIndex, GlyphIndex, &sFonts[FontIndex].Glyphs[GlyphIndex]);
    }

    fclose(File);
}

void Font_ReadGlyphInternal(FILE* File, int unsigned FontIndex, short unsigned GlyphIndex, Glyph* Result)
{
    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphOffsets[GlyphIndex], SEEK_SET);

    Result->NumOfContours = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    Result->MinX = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    Result->MinY = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    Result->MaxX = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    Result->MaxY = FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
    Result->IsCompound = Result->NumOfContours < 0;

    if (Result->IsCompound)
    {
        Font_ReadCompoundGlyphInternal(File, FontIndex, GlyphIndex, Result);
    }
    else
    {
        Font_ReadSimpleGlyphInternal(File, Result);
    }
}

void Font_ReadSimpleGlyphInternal(FILE* File, Glyph* Result)
{
    if (Result->NumOfContours == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Result->ContourEndIndices = (short unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(Result->NumOfContours * sizeof(short unsigned), 0);
    FileReader_ReadUInt16Array(File, true, Result->ContourEndIndices, (int unsigned)Result->NumOfContours);

    Result->NumOfPoints = Result->ContourEndIndices[Result->NumOfContours - 1U] + 1U;
    Result->Points = (GlyphPoint*)Memory_Alloc(Result->NumOfPoints * sizeof(GlyphPoint), 0);
    Result->Flags = (char unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(Result->NumOfPoints, 0);

    Result->NumOfInstructions = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    Result->Instructions = (char unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(Result->NumOfInstructions, 0);
    FileReader_ReadUInt8Array(File, Result->Instructions, Result->NumOfInstructions);

    for (short unsigned PointIndex = 0; PointIndex < Result->NumOfPoints; PointIndex++)
    {
        Result->Flags[PointIndex] = FileReader_ReadUInt8(File);
        if (IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], REPEAT_FLAG_BIT))
        {
            char unsigned RepeatCount = FileReader_ReadUInt8(File);
            for (char unsigned RepeatIndex = 0; RepeatIndex < RepeatCount; RepeatIndex++)
            {
                Result->Flags[++PointIndex] = Result->Flags[PointIndex - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    short CoordX = 0;
    short CoordY = 0;

    for (short unsigned PointIndex = 0; PointIndex < Result->NumOfPoints; PointIndex++)
    {
        if (IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], X_SHORT_VECTOR_BIT))
        {
            char CoordOffset = FileReader_ReadInt8(File);
            CoordX += IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], X_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR) ? CoordOffset : -CoordOffset;
        }
        else if (IS_BIT_NOT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], X_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR))
        {
            CoordX += FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
        }

        Result->Points[PointIndex].X = CoordX;
        Result->Points[PointIndex].OnCurve = IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], ON_CURVE_POINT_BIT);
    }

    for (short unsigned PointIndex = 0; PointIndex < Result->NumOfPoints; PointIndex++)
    {
        if (IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], Y_SHORT_VECTOR_BIT))
        {
            char CoordOffset = FileReader_ReadInt8(File);
            CoordY += IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], Y_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR) ? CoordOffset : -CoordOffset;
        }
        else if (IS_BIT_NOT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], Y_IS_SAME_OR_POSITIVE_SHORT_VECTOR))
        {
            CoordY += FileReader_ReadInt16(File, true);
        }

        Result->Points[PointIndex].Y = CoordY;
        Result->Points[PointIndex].OnCurve = IS_BIT_SET(Result->Flags[PointIndex], ON_CURVE_POINT_BIT);
    }
}

Glyph* Font_GlyphByUnicode(int unsigned FontIndex, int unsigned Unicode)
{
    long long unsigned GlyphMapCount = Vector_Count(sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphMapping);

    for (long long unsigned GlyphMapIndex = 0; GlyphMapIndex < GlyphMapCount; GlyphMapIndex++)
    {
        GlyphMap* GlyphMapping = (GlyphMap*)Vector_At(sFonts[FontIndex].GlyphMapping, GlyphMapIndex);

        if (GlyphMapping->Unicode == Unicode)
        {
            return &sFonts[FontIndex].Glyphs[GlyphMapping->GlyphIndex];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void DrawGlyphContours(Matrix4 Projection, Matrix4 View, float Scale)
{
    for (short unsigned GlyphIndex = 'A'; GlyphIndex <= 'Z'; GlyphIndex++)
    {
        Glyph* Glyph = Font_GlyphByUnicode(FONT_MAIN, GlyphIndex);

        Gizmo_BeginPoints();
        for (short unsigned PointIndex = 0; PointIndex < Glyph->NumOfPoints; PointIndex++)
        {
            float FromX = (float)Glyph->Points[PointIndex].X / Scale;
            float FromY = (float)Glyph->Points[PointIndex].Y / Scale;

            Gizmo_DrawPointSimple(OffsetX + FromX, OffsetY + FromY, 0.0F, 0.02F, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
        Gizmo_EndPoints(Projection, View);

        Gizmo_BeginLines();
        short unsigned ContourStartIndex = 0;
        for (short unsigned ContourIndex = 0; ContourIndex < Glyph->NumOfContours; ContourIndex++)
        {
            short unsigned ContourEndIndex = Glyph->ContourEndIndices[ContourIndex];
            short unsigned NumOfContourPoints = (short unsigned)(ContourEndIndex - ContourStartIndex);

            for (short unsigned PointIndex = ContourStartIndex; PointIndex < (ContourStartIndex + NumOfContourPoints); PointIndex++)
            {
                float FromX = (float)Glyph->Points[PointIndex].X / Scale;
                float FromY = (float)Glyph->Points[PointIndex].Y / Scale;
                float ToX = (float)Glyph->Points[(PointIndex + 1) % Glyph->NumOfPoints].X / Scale;
                float ToY = (float)Glyph->Points[(PointIndex + 1) % Glyph->NumOfPoints].Y / Scale;

                Gizmo_DrawLineSimple(OffsetX + FromX, OffsetY + FromY, 0.0F, OffsetX + ToX, OffsetY + ToY, 0.0F, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            }

            float FromX = (float)Glyph->Points[ContourEndIndex].X / Scale;
            float FromY = (float)Glyph->Points[ContourEndIndex].Y / Scale;
            float ToX = (float)Glyph->Points[ContourStartIndex].X / Scale;
            float ToY = (float)Glyph->Points[ContourStartIndex].Y / Scale;

            Gizmo_DrawLineSimple(OffsetX + FromX, OffsetY + FromY, 0.0F, OffsetX + ToX, OffsetY + ToY, 0.0F, 0xFFFFFFFF);

            ContourStartIndex = ContourEndIndex + 1U;
        }
        Gizmo_EndLines(Projection, View);

    }
}

Vector* Font_UnicodeToGlyphMappingsInternal(FILE* File, int unsigned FontIndex)
{
    Vector* GlyphMapping = Vector_Alloc(sizeof(GlyphMap));

    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTableDir.Offset + (long)sizeof(FontCmapTable), SEEK_SET);

    int SelectedUnicodeVersionID = -1;
    int unsigned CmapSubTableOffset = 0;
    for (int unsigned SubTableIndex = 0; SubTableIndex < sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTable.NumberSubTables; SubTableIndex++)
    {
        FontCmapSubTable CmapSubTable = {};
        CmapSubTable.PlatformID = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        CmapSubTable.Offset = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);

        if (CmapSubTable.PlatformID == 0)
        {
            if ((CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 0) ||
                (CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 1) ||
                (CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 3) ||
                (CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 4) &&
                (CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID > SelectedUnicodeVersionID))
            {
                CmapSubTableOffset = CmapSubTable.Offset;
                SelectedUnicodeVersionID = CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID;
            }
        }
        else if ((CmapSubTable.PlatformID == 3) && (SelectedUnicodeVersionID == -1))
        {
            if ((CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 1) ||
                (CmapSubTable.PlatformSpecificID == 10))
            {
                CmapSubTableOffset = CmapSubTable.Offset;
            }
        }
    }
    assert(CmapSubTableOffset);

    fseek(File, (long)sFonts[FontIndex].CmapTableDir.Offset + (long)CmapSubTableOffset, SEEK_SET);

    short unsigned Format = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
    assert((Format == 4) || (Format == 12));

    bool HasMissingGlyphs = false;

    switch (Format)
    {
    case 4:
    {
        short unsigned Length = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned Language = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned SegCountX2 = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned SearchRange = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned EntrySelector = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned RangeShift = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        short unsigned SegCount = SegCountX2 / 2U;

        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Length);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Language);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(SearchRange);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(EntrySelector);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RangeShift);

        short unsigned* EndCodes = (short unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(SegCount * sizeof(short unsigned), 0);
        FileReader_ReadUInt16Array(File, true, EndCodes, SegCount);

        short unsigned Reserved = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Reserved);

        short unsigned* StartCodes = (short unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(SegCount * sizeof(short unsigned), 0);
        FileReader_ReadUInt16Array(File, true, StartCodes, SegCount);

        short unsigned* IDDeltas = (short unsigned*)Memory_Alloc(SegCount * sizeof(short unsigned), 0);
        FileReader_ReadUInt16Array(File, true, IDDeltas, SegCount);

        struct IDRangeOffsetMap
        {
            int unsigned ReadLocation;
            short unsigned RangeOffset;
        };
        IDRangeOffsetMap* IDRangeOffsets = (IDRangeOffsetMap*)Memory_Alloc(SegCount * sizeof(IDRangeOffsetMap), 0);

        for (short unsigned SegmentIndex = 0; SegmentIndex < SegCount; SegmentIndex++)
        {
            IDRangeOffsets[SegmentIndex].ReadLocation = (int unsigned)ftell(File);
            IDRangeOffsets[SegmentIndex].RangeOffset = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        }

        for (short unsigned SegmentIndex = 0; SegmentIndex < SegCount; SegmentIndex++)
        {
            int unsigned EndCode = EndCodes[SegmentIndex];
            int unsigned CurrCode = StartCodes[SegmentIndex];

            if (CurrCode == 0xFFFFU)
            {
                break;
            }

            while (CurrCode <= EndCode)
            {
                short unsigned GlyphIndex = 0;

                if (IDRangeOffsets[SegmentIndex].RangeOffset == 0)
                {
                    GlyphIndex = (CurrCode + IDDeltas[SegmentIndex]) % 0x10000U;
                }
                else
                {
                    int unsigned StoredLocation = (int unsigned)ftell(File);
                    int unsigned RangeOffsetLocation = IDRangeOffsets[SegmentIndex].ReadLocation + IDRangeOffsets[SegmentIndex].RangeOffset;
                    int unsigned GlyphIndexArrayLocation = 2U * (CurrCode - StartCodes[SegmentIndex]) + RangeOffsetLocation;

                    fseek(File, (long)GlyphIndexArrayLocation, SEEK_SET);

                    GlyphIndex = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);

                    if (GlyphIndex != 0)
                    {
                        GlyphIndex = (GlyphIndex + IDDeltas[SegmentIndex]) % 0x10000U;
                    }

                    fseek(File, (long)StoredLocation, SEEK_SET);
                }

                GlyphMap Mapping = { GlyphIndex, CurrCode };
                Vector_Push(GlyphMapping, &Mapping);

                HasMissingGlyphs |= GlyphIndex == 0;
                CurrCode++;
            }
        }

        Memory_Free(EndCodes);
        Memory_Free(StartCodes);
        Memory_Free(IDDeltas);
        Memory_Free(IDRangeOffsets);

        break;
    }
    case 12:
    {
        short unsigned Reserved = FileReader_ReadUInt16(File, true);
        int unsigned Length = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
        int unsigned Language = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
        int unsigned NumGroups = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);

        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Reserved);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Length);
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Language);

        for (int unsigned GroupIndex = 0; GroupIndex < NumGroups; GroupIndex++)
        {
            int unsigned StartCharCode = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
            int unsigned EndCharCode = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
            int unsigned StartGlyphCode = FileReader_ReadUInt32(File, true);
            int unsigned NumOfChars = EndCharCode - StartCharCode + 1;

            for (int unsigned CharIndex = 0; CharIndex < NumOfChars; CharIndex++)
            {
                short unsigned GlyphIndex = (short unsigned)(StartGlyphCode + CharIndex);
                int unsigned CharCode = StartCharCode + CharIndex;

                GlyphMap Mapping = { GlyphIndex, CharCode };
                Vector_Push(GlyphMapping, &Mapping);

                HasMissingGlyphs |= GlyphIndex == 0;
            }
        }

        break;
    }
    }

    if (HasMissingGlyphs == 0)
    {
        GlyphMap Mapping = { 0, 0xFFFF };
        Vector_Push(GlyphMapping, &Mapping);
    }

    return GlyphMapping;
}


Your code calls lots of functions that you have not shown us. You have an image, but clearly the code you provided does not make images. Can't you make some kind of [mre] that we could test with?

I've added all missing functions.. but I strongly believe that it is just a minor error.

Hello @Michael. That is still not an example that we can copy/paste and run. And your question smell "do my homework".

Do you really ask us to debug hundreds of lines of code?

"I've added all missing functions." --> FileReader_ReadInt16(), Vector_Count(), many #includes, types, etc. are all missing.  Post an [MCVE].
